# Tiling with dominoes then with tetrominoes

Tags: tiling, polyomino

For reference, here are the five tetrominoes:

[image: All five tetrominoes]

Suppose you join ten dominoes to make a polyomino made of twenty unit squares.  Is it possible that you can tile the polyomino using all the five given tetrominoes (each exactly once)?  You can rotate and/or turn over any of the tetrominoes.

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear to me: when I first read it I understood that the task was to figure out whether it is always possible to tile the large polyminos no matter its shape. Looking at the accepted answer I understood you were asking whether it is possible to find at least one "tilable" large polymino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> No.  To see that it is impossible, use a checkerboard coloring.  Each domino covers one black and one red square, but the five tetrominoes have two more of one color than the other (because of the T).